# Am trying to write live data from an online csv

Tags: python, grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2, influxdb-python

On the Web UI, it only shows tags without fields. The data only appears later, after I shut down my PC. Below is my code. I scheduled the data to be written every 15 seconds, but it does not show any data on the web. Th code runs with no errors Please help

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import schedule
import time

from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

# You can generate a Token from the "Tokens Tab" in the UI
token = "9o2rIXlQSgAUEzLmRl8wrEjDGKJMe9vyHw_sk1fBuJ1OJVCHJBdH_muJ6SiGsd7VpcU-LVTdNjhNcw7nR56dZA=="
org = "Filtrona"
bucket = "Machines3"

client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token=token)
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)

# Configure the batch size for data points
batch_size = 25

def fetch_and_store_data():
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv("http://10.9.161.25/dataList.csv", skiprows = [1])
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace(r'(\w+)\. (\d+)', r'\1 \2', regex=True), format="%Y-%b %d. %H:%M:%S")
        df.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)

        # Batch data points and write in batches
        for chunk in range(0, len(df), batch_size):
            batch_data = df.iloc[chunk:chunk + batch_size]
            write_api.write(bucket, org, record=batch_data, data_frame_measurement_name="Machine",
                            data_frame_tag_columns=['ID'])
            print(f"Batch of {batch_size} data points fetched and stored in InfluxDB., Data Below:")
            print(df)

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)

# Schedule the fetch_and_store_data function to run every 2 seconds
schedule.every(20).seconds.do(fetch_and_store_data)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(19)
```

Am I doing something wrong?